# Flutter PageView initialPage acts strange on specific indices

Tags: flutter

The code below shows my problem. When I set initialPage in the PageController to for example 0 or 1 this code prints the initialPage. However when I set the initialPage to 5 it not only prints 5 but also 6 and in the Flutter Performance tab I can also all of a sudden see Two pages being loaded instead of the normal and expected 1 for some reason. I have this same problem when I set the initialPage to 11. Is there a reason for this happening and perhaps a workaround for it?

And if this is a 'feature' from Flutter, what could be a good alternative for PageView.builder when you don't want an unnecessarily loaded page?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageViewTest extends StatelessWidget {
  final PageController controller = PageController(initialPage: 5);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
          controller: controller,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            print(index);
            return Center(child: Text(index.toString()));
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you wanna set the initial page to 5 for example. Don't hot restart the app, but rather stop it completely (Ctrl+F2) and then run it again.

Comment: It's more that I have another page that passes an index as a constructor for the initialPage to this Page and then I want the widget with the initialIndex to be displayed first. However widgets that contain index 5 of 11 now make this code in my example crash because of the strange behaviour I described, whilst it works fine on all other indices.

Comment: I also noticed this issue in 1.22.6, but it seems to be fixed in Flutter 2.0.3. See this Github issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68182